# Cannot empty Vue computed array property

Tags: arrays, vue.js, watch

Hy!

I want to change a Vue computed array in watch, but it doesn't empty that. The array push is working, but before that, the truncate is not.

What's the problem? Any idea?

Thanks!

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    data: {
        form: {
            strFirstName: null,
            strLastName: null,
            strPhone: null,
            numStartTime: 11,
            numEndTime: 18
        }
    },
    computed: {
        rowEndTime: function() {
            var rowTime = [];
            for (var i = 11; i < 19; i++) {
                rowTime.push(i);
            }
            return rowTime;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'form.numStartTime': function(numNewStartTime) {
            this.rowEndTime = [];

            for (var i = numNewStartTime; i < 19; i++) {
                this.rowEndTime.push(i);
                if (this.form.numEndTime <= numNewStartTime) {
                    this.form.numEndTime = numNewStartTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should be pushing/truncating from a `data` attribute, not a computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what computed properties are for - [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property](http://Vue%20Documentation)

You just can watch some values in the function of the computed property.

In your case:

```
computed: {
    rowEndTime: function() {
        var rowTime = [];
        for (var i = this.form.numStartTime; i < 19; i++) {
            rowTime.push(i);
        }
        return rowTime;
    }
}
```